# trigger('reloadGrid') does'nt work on IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

On IE 8, when calling `trigger('reloadGrid')` on jqGrid object, the grid looks like been loaded and its also been emptying.

my code:

```
$('#myList').setGridParam({page:1});
$('#myList').setGridParam(url: 'http://..');
$('#myList').trigger('reloadGrid');
```

In Chrome the request is sent to the server and the data is been refreshed appropriately.

**EDIT:** The request is sent to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-inspecting the request, the request did reach the server but its URL parameter was in Unicode character(U+05D0-א-Hebrew Letter Alef).

IE does not automatically encoding the URL in contrary to Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

IE use client Cache.. So make sure that caching is disabled for Code.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]        
public ActionResult GetArea(int locationId)
```

Comment: I've tried adding `&timeStamp = new Data.GetTime()` query string to the `url` parameter but it's not helped.